# Can you salvage a plan/pattern?

Tags: diablo-iii

Diablo 3 has a pretty good loot system for patterns in the case of, if your blacksmith or jeweler know the pattern it won't drop again.

However, thanks to the legendary drop buff special event this week, I had the unfortunate luck of having a pattern drop at the start of a rift and then it dropped again at the end when we killed the rift guardian due to me not having gone back to town yet to teach my blacksmith the pattern.

In my haste/disgust I simply sold the plan for a measly 122 gold. Today I came to think, could I have not salvaged the plan for a forgotten soul?

Comment: Hmm, I had the problem that I kept getting jewelcrafting recipe drops because I hadn't upgraded him just yet so I couldn't learn the recipes. In the end I had 5 patterns for 1 kind of gem, I just dropped them on the ground. Didn't think of selling them :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, no, you can't.  Plans are unsalvageable.  What you did is the only thing you *can* do with duplicate plans.  Or just drop it on the ground.

Trying to check Blizzard's site, plans don't even have their own page.  You can [see the list of plans](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blacksmith-plan/#type=legendary), but clicking on one just brings you to the crafted item.

Comment: Could also trade it ... can't remember if plans tend to be bind on account.

Comment: Oh, they're definitely account bound.  Blizzard's killed the economy as hard as they could.  Or at least, every plan at blacksmith's level 12 is account bound.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't. I always return to town immediately to teach my blacksmith when I get a plan to avoid this situation occurring.